# Twitter API - get tweets with id_str

Tags: api, twitter

Sorry , I have a problem with this script :
It's for get tweet with specific id ;

```
$tweetlist = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=694658584664236033');

foreach ($tweetlist->statuses as $key => $value) {

    $message = utf8_decode($value->text);
    echo $message;
}
```

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Thank you so much for your help
Nicolas

Comment: Just as the error message says, an invalid argument is supplied to foreach. Print your tweetlist variable and look inside. Does it have an element called statuses? If so, what is its type?

Answer (score 0):

remove `->statuses`, like:

```
$tweetlist = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json?id=694658584664236033');

foreach ($tweetlist as $key => $value) {

$message = utf8_decode($value->text);
echo $message;
}
```

Comment: It's OK without foreach, Thank you so much Mounir !